# ignore/skip/omit joint duplicate attribute values completely in XSLT

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I am new to xslt stuff.
I tried to follow example groupby, distinct, sibling approach from this forum and also tried code mentioned in other website such as <https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-cookbook/0596003722/ch04s03.html> but not getting what i want. I am also trying with generate-id approach but getting some errors.

Here is my **input** which is always in un-sorted form.

```
<root>
    <record>
        <firstname>a</firstname>
        <lastname>f</lastname>
        <phone>8</phone>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>b</firstname>
        <lastname>f</lastname>          
        <phone>2</phone>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>a</firstname>
        <lastname>f</lastname>
        <phone>8</phone>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>b</firstname>
        <lastname>e</lastname>          
        <phone>2</phone>
    </record>
</root>
```

and below output is expected i.e. ignore duplicate values (firstname+lastname) completely.

```
<root> 
    <record>
        <firstname>b</firstname>
        <lastname>e</lastname>          
        <phone>2</phone>
    </record>
    <record>
        <firstname>b</firstname>
        <lastname>f</lastname>          
        <phone>2</phone>
    </record>
</root>
```

so far, only sorting is working.

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: I just checked its XSLT 1.2.

Comment: There is no such thing as XSLT 1.2. And I asked which processor, not which version of XSLT.

Comment: XSLT 3.0 processor in SAP CPI is Saxon-EE by Saxonica. However I am first trying to test the code through https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3.0 you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="firstname, lastname" composite="yes">
            <xsl:copy-of select=".[count(current-group())=1]" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ohh. I thought by clicking on upvoting it should closed the questiosns. Clicked on accepted now. Thank you!